# Atlanta Terminal Change: Domestic to International with Bags

Tags: transit, atlanta, atl

I am arriving at ATL on Delta and connecting to Qatar Airways. They have no "baggage agreement".

How do I get from the South terminal baggage claim area to International (F) to recheck bags on Qatar? I have 2.5 hours if I arrive on time. Would this be enough?

Answer (score 3):

2.5 hours is pretty tight for a separate connection, but you ought to be able to do it if your inbound flght isn't significantly late.

After you claim your baggage in the domestic terminal, follow the signs for the International Shuttle Connector. This free shuttle runs between the domestic and international terminals at ATL and takes about 15 minutes.

[image: ATL Domestic terminal signage]

After you arrive at the international terminal you'll be able to check in and check your bags at the Qatar desks. Keep in mind that you must be checked in and your bags dropped at least 60 minutes before departure.

Comment: And keep in mind that if you miss the check-in/baggage drop deadline, you’ll be considered a no-show, and unless you have a very flexible fare, your ticket will be cancelled, you’ll have to rebook at your expense (which may be very expensive at the last minute), pay for hotels, etc. Better make sure you have travel insurance that covers this situation (and check their conditions).